# Selecting distinct entities across a large google app engine table

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this problem.

We have an idea we'd like to implement, and we're currently unable to do this efficiently.

I've anonymised the data as best as possible, but the structure is the same.

We have two entities, Car and CarJourney. Each Car has 0 to many CarJourney's. Each Car Journey has (amongst other properties) a date associated with it - the date the journey was started.

I wish to query by time over car journeys. I'll have two times, a start date and an end date, where start date <= endDate, and I want to receive the most recently started journey in that period.

So, if I had a particular car in mind, say car 123, I'd write a query that limits by Car.key and Car.startDate, where Car.key == 123 and Journey.startDate >= startDate and Journey.startDate <= endDate with an ordering on Journey.startDate descending and a limit of 1.

e.g. Car A has 3 journeys, taken on 1st, 2nd and the 3rd of the month. The query start date is 1st and the query end date is the 2nd. The result of this query would be one Car journey, the 2nd.

Once the result of that query is returned, a very small amount of processing is done to return a result to the user.

That's the easy bit.

But, instead of over 1 Car, I want a list of cars, where the list contains N keys to cars.

So, I want to run the above query N times, once for every car. And I want the latest journey for each car.

Because the time range is flexible (and thus can't be known beforehand) we can't implement a "isMostRecent" flag, because while it might be the most recent for now, it might not be the most recent for the specified date parameters.

We also need to ensure that this returns promptly (current queries are around the 3-5 second mark for a small set of data) as this goes straight back to the user. This means that we can't use task queues, and because the specified dates are arbitrary we can't implement mass indexing of "isWithinDate" fields.

We tried using an async query, but because the amount of processing is negligible the bottleneck is still the queries on the datastore (because the async api still sends the requests synchronously, it just doesn't block).

Ideally, we'd implement this as a select on car journeys ordered by startDate where the Car.key is distinct, but we can't seem to pull this off in GAE.

There are numerous small optimisations we can make (for example, some MemCaching of repeated queries) but none have made a significant dent in our query time. And MemCaching can only help for a maximum of 1-2 minutes (due to the inevitable forward march of time!)

Any ideas are most welcome and highly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Ed

Comment: I don't know how many cars and journeys you have, and what the interval between the two dates is. But maybe it would be quicker to just ask for all the journeys of the cars in the period (1 query instead of 1 query per car) and filter the results in Java?

Comment: The interval between the dates is at minimum 1 minute and maximum of 2 months. The number of cars could be 2000, making journeys every 3 seconds (this is where my car analogy falls down!). So, in the space of 2 months we're looking at around 1.8 billion journeys (in the worst case).

Comment: Just for reference, I've also posted this on Google Groups: [link](http://goo.gl/hKX53). I'll try and keep both updated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the best option is to execute the many queries yourself. You say you tried asynchronous queries, but the bottleneck was sending the query. This seems extremely odd - you should be able to have many queries in flight at the same time, substantially cutting down your latency. How did you determine this?

Comment: We determined it using good old "click the button and see how long it takes" and then followed it up by using the appstats feature of App Engine. The bottleneck is not sending the query, it's sending the _queries_. If the query was one massive query, I think it would work asynchronously just fine. But one massive query would violate Googles 30 sub queries limitation. You're right though, it does seem odd. Just for reference, below is a copy paste of my understanding that I wrote to another user. If you can prove me wrong, I'd be the happiest man alive ;)

Comment: That's an interesting idea. However the Asynchronous api actually 
fires the requests synchronously, it just doesn't block. (Or at least, that's my experience). So, at the moment we fire off 1 query (which Google turns into 2) for each car. And although the method call returns instantly, it still takes ~5 seconds in total with basic test data. (Comment continued below...)

Comment: If each call takes 12ms, we still have to wait 24 seconds for 2,000 cars. So, the first call starts at time 0, the second call starts at 0+12, the third at 0+12+12... etc. With 2,000 sites, this works out about 24 seconds. Once you've added in the overheads and getting the list of Cars in the first place, it's too long. 
If we could start even 100 queries at the same time of time 0, that'd 
be superb. We thought we could do it with multithreading, but that's 
not allowed on App Engine.

Comment: @edhgoose Multiqueries (Eg, with in or != filters) are broken up into subqueries by the SDK, so they're in all ways equivalent to making multiple backend queries yourself. How are you doing async queries? Sending the query shouldn't take anything like ~25ms. On the other hand, if you're really trying to do 2,000 queries, perhaps you need to reconsider what you're doing. Can your user really absorb the information generate by 2,000 queries in a single page?

Comment: Nick - We're doing the async queries as multiple multi-queries. So, each car has one query (which is split into 2 queries). Each of these takes ~6ms, so ~12ms in total. Multiply that by 2000 and you get the 24seconds. Yes - you are absolutely correct, querying over 2000 cars is too much data and we have got methods for resolving this. We'd be plotting the cars on a map, where the size of the map is quite large. So, 500 wouldn't be an unreasonable number, so we'd still be looking at 5-6 seconds. Too long in web world!

Comment: @edhgoose Multiqueries are not (currently) async, so you're actually doing the queries entirely in serial. If you want to do async queries right now, your best option is to use Guido's NDB library. Since you're populating a map, why not fetch just those elements within the viewport, and do so asynchronously in the background, so the map populates after the page has loaded?

Comment: @Nick - We've already limited the cars by viewport, thanks for that, and I've suggested that we do populate the map as it loads. We've currently put in a simple stop gap solution (i.e. change the requirements), and then we're going to investigate solutions like yours. Hopefully I'll get back to you (and StackOverflow) in the next 2 weeks as to what we've done! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd recommend using [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine). JDO/JPA on appengine just fool people into thinking that appengine datastore is just a SQL database, which, as you realized, is far from the truth.

If I understand correctly you have a Car which contains a List of CarJourneys?

List properties on appengine are limited to 5000 entries and any time you access/change them they have to be serialized/deserialized in whole. So if you plan to have a lot of CarJourneys per Car than this will get slow. Also because appengine creates an index entry for every value in the collection this can lead to [exploding indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes).

Instead, just create a property Car inside CarJourney that points to the Car that made the journey: a one-to-one relationship from CarJourney to Car. The type can be Key or just string/long containing the id of the Car. When querying just add filter for Car property.

I suggest watching Brett Slatkin's video: [Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8).

Comment: Sorry, the Car and the Car Journey are two separate entity types. So a Car Journey contains the key to the Car. We expect a car to be making at maximum a journey every 3 seconds (the car analogy has fallen down a bit here), so an individual car could be making almost 900,000 journeys a month. As in my comment above - we could have 2,000 cars, thus 900,000*2000 = 1.8billion car journeys.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one query and filter distinct cars by yourself. Like `select CarJouney startDate >= startDate and startDate <= endDate order by startData` and iterate (+filter on your side) through this query until you find enough data to show.

Comment: I've added a comment to the first post - but just in case you skim past - we've too much data! We also can't guarantee that the CarJourneys will be in any sort of order. If one car makes journeys all the time, we don't want to show it over a car that makes infrequent journeys (which is what the order by start date effectively does).

Answer (score 0):

Denormalization should solve your problem - having a last_journey reference property in your car, so everytime you start a journey, you'd also update the Car entity - this way you'd be able to query all cars and have their lastest journey on the resultset.
It's worth noting that when you access last_journey, a new get() will be issued to the datastore, so if you're listing a lot of cars, you could build a list with all the last_journey keys and fetch then all at once passing that to db.get().

[Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8) is definately a must watch (sadly the sound is terrible on this video)

Comment: Hi guigouz - if I'm understanding correctly - you suggest that we have a link from each car to it's recent journey? This is something we already implemented as a stop gap solution / optimisation. This works fine if your start date (oldest date) is sometime in the past and your end date (newest date) is now. However, if I said I want to look at journeys that were between 1 and 2 months old (but not newer), the last_journey isn't correct. The last_journey might have been yesterday, which is outside of the 1 to 2 months ago range.

Comment: I thought you only needed details about the last journey when dealing with many cars... The datastore is really low level, and the solutions are usually really smart. I'll post another suggestion if I find some solution. In the meanwhile, the appengine Google I/O videos may shed a light for you and your team.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same kind of problem some time ago. 
I tried some solutions (in memory sort and 
filtering, encoding things into keys etc. and I have benchmarked those 
for both latency and cpu cycles using some test data around 100K 
entities) 
An other approach I have taken is encoding the date as an integer (day 
since start of epoch or day since start of year, same for hour of day 
or month depending on how much detail you need in your output) and 
saving this into a property. This way you turn your date query filter 
into an equality only filter which does not even needs to specify an 
index) then you can sort or filter on other properties. 
Benchmarking the latest solution I have found that when the filtered 
result set is a small fraction of the unfiltered original set, is  1+ 
order of magnitude faster and cpu-eficient. Worst case when no 
reduction of the result set due to filtering the latency and cpu usage 
was comparable to the previous solutions)

Hope this helps, or did I missed something ?

Happy coding-:)

Comment: It's a really good idea, but: because we're looking for the latest journey in a unknown time frame, you can't store a how many days old it is (or equivalent), because if a car stopped making journeys for a week, the last journey would have a "days old" or equivalent of -7. But, in a time frame between now (0) and 2 weeks ago (-14) we would need that journey (because it's the latest). In a time frame of now (0) to 3 days ago (-3) though, we must not show that journey. You end up doing a > 0 and <= 3 again.

Comment: The alternative is to turn your singular field into N fields (say, 1 for each day/hour) for the time frame we need. So in our example, we want to look at journeys over a 2 month period. We could then have a true/false value on each field as to whether to show that journey in a given selection. So in the example above, the journey made 7 days ago would have -7, -6, -5 ... 0 all set to true and -8 onwards to false. But because of the inevitable forwardness of time maintaining that set of fields gets difficult. Add in the 100 index limit and things get difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make this queries in parallel by calling it right from client, using ajax. I mean that you can return to the user an empty html page, just with cars definitions, and then make ajax calls for journeys for every car on this page.

Answer (score -1):

As JB nizet suggested I am wondering if the answer might be something such as a single query, possibly with a temporary table, or anonymous intermediate table (I don't know what google supports to this end) using a group by (thus eliminating extra transfer of data and the need for Java to do the processing). I am thinking something along the lines of

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 AS
SELECT * FROM car_journey
WHERE start_date > ? AND
end_date < ?

SELECT car_id, journey_id
FROM temp1 t1, (
  SELECT car_id, MIN(start_date)
  FROM temp1
  GROUP BY car_id 
) t2
WHERE t1.car_id = t2.car_id AND
t1.start_date = t2.start_date
```

With the temporary table you can greatly reduce the time for the secondary query, since theoretically the data will be much smaller than the full table.

Finally, again not knowing what google supports, I would ask if you have indices defined on the appropriate columns, which may help speed up the query.

Comment: the app engine datastore is not SQL based or even relational.  Nor does it have the concept of intermediate tables.  Actually, it doesn't even have the concept of regular tables :)

Comment: It's something we've definitely thought of. If there is a equivalent idea/concept we could use that might work.